# difference between css and Styled in emotion js

Tags: emotion

I started learning css-in-js with emotion js.

can someone tell me if there is actually a difference between

```
const Component = Styled('div')`
  color: 'red'
`;
```

and

```
const Component = () => (
  <div className={css`color: red`}/>
)
```

1. Is it Styled some sort of helper or shorthand of css?
2. Is there a recommendation when to use which?

looks like all Styled can do, can be replaced by css + cx

Answer (score 3):

I think the main difference would be that `css` just generates a selector with 
a specific set of CSS properties, whereas `styled` requires a component to attach the styles to (i.e. a `div` like in your example).

If you want to style multiple/different elements with `css` you'd write

```
const specificStyle = css`
  color: red
`
<ComponentThatRendersADiv className={specificStyle} />
<ComponentThatRendersASpan className={specificStyle} />
<ComponentThatRendersAButton className={specificStyle} />
```

If you wanted to style a certain component with `styled` and reuse it:

```
const ComponentThatRendersADiv = styled('div')`
  color: red
`
const ComponentThatRendersASpan = ComponentThatRendersADiv.withComponent('span')
const ComponentThatRendersAButton = ComponentThatRendersADiv.withComponent('button')

<ComponentThatRendersADiv />
<ComponentThatRendersASpan />
<ComponentThatRendersAButton />
```

So `css` feels more like the typical way of writing CSS where you create selectors that are applied to elements/components.

`styled` creates a specific composition/component.

Docs for `styled`: https://emotion.sh/docs/styled
Docs for `css`: https://emotion.sh/docs/css